# Powershell New-Item: How to Accept Confirmation Automatically

Tags: powershell, confirm

I'm trying to create a new directory on a network drive using a powershell script but it keeps prompting me

> "Confirm: Are you sure you want to perform this action ...."

Is there a way to override this so it doesn't ask me since I'm running this script from a web interface.

Here is my call:

```
New-Item $rollbackDirectory -type Directory -Force
```

It does the same thing, with or without the `-Force` parameter

I've also tried this format with no luck

```
New-Item -name $rollbackName -itemtype directory -path $rollbackdrive -Debug -Force
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`-confirm` need only be specified when you want the cmdlet to prompt you for confirmation. Whether the cmdlet by itself would prompt for confirmation or not depends on the developer of the cmdlet who can set a high, medium, low for the cmdlet based on its effect. Based on the value of `$ConfirmPreference` you will get the confirmation automatically for a cmdlet. The default value for `$ConfirmPreference` is high and the level set for `New-Item` is medium. So if the `New-Item` is prompting for confirmation, the `$ConfirmPreference` value must have been changed to medium or low.

Change it using `$ConfirmPreference="high"` or even `$ConfirmPreference="none"` to make `New-Item` not prompt, or your solution of `-confirm:$false` works as well by overriding the `$ConfirmPreference`.

Explained perfectly here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2006/12/15/confirmpreference.aspx

Hope this clears it up.

Answer (score 14):

I ended up trying this (even though I read on another SO post that it is not correct):

```
New-Item $rollbackDirectory -type Directory -Force -Confirm:$false
```

And it worked! Hope this helps others with the same issue

Comment: `-Confirm:$false` is perfectly valid way for doing this at a cmdlet level. Also, see my answer.

Comment: but what value will be selected?(A,B,C A is default) default? What if we want to accept non-default value(B,C,A) and move on to next statement?