# How do I set $ConfirmPreference = "None" for a PowerShell instance?

Tags: c#, powershell

I am trying to run `PowerShell` scripts using `C#` using [this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kebab/archive/2014/04/28/executing-powershell-scripts-from-c.aspx) as a reference.

So far I have got:

```
  try
  {
       using (PowerShell PowerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create())
       {
             PowerShellInstance.AddCommand(scriptPath);                      
             var PSOutput = PowerShellInstance.Invoke();
             if (PowerShellInstance.Streams.Error.Count > 0)
             {
                 foreach (var line in PowerShellInstance.Streams.Error)
                 {
                      Console.WriteLine(line);
                 }
                 return false;
             }
             else
             {
                 return true;
             }
        }
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
       return false;
   }
```

Which keeps throwing an exception:

> **"AuthorizationManager check failed."**
>
> **Inner Exception:** A command that prompts the user failed because the
>   host program or the command
>   type does not support user interaction. The host was attempting to
>   request confirmation with the following message: Run only scripts that
>   you trust. While scripts from the internet can be useful, this script
>   can potentially harm your computer. If you trust this script, use the
>   Unblock-File cmdlet to allow the script to run without this warning
>   message. Do you want to run C:\PowerShellScripts\MyScript.ps1?

So looking at the `Exception` I can see it's asking me to confirm the script but there is no window for the user to interact, hence the exception.

So I started looking at how to stop the confirmation text and found [Powershell New-Item: How to Accept Confirmation Automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6950452/2987066)

But even adding:

```
PowerShellInstance.AddScript("$ConfirmPreference = \"None\"");
PowerShellInstance.Invoke();
```

Before executing my script didn't work. So is there a way of setting `$ConfirmPreference = "None"` for my PowerShell instance using `C#`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it has something to do with the Execution Policy. You can query the execution policy with the Cmdlet `Get-ExecutionPolicy`. You can:

1. change the Execution Policy to (for example): "Unrestricted" by
   using `Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted` or
2. run your script by running `powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass C:\PowerShellScripts\MyScript.ps1` or
3. unblock the script by using the Cmdlet `Unblock-File C:\PowerShellScripts\MyScript.ps1`

Comment: My execution policy is already `Unrestricted`. I think the problem lies more with the `ConfirmationPreference` further info found [Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2006/12/15/confirmpreference.aspx)

Comment: The files were `Blocked` though and Manually going through and unblocking them worked. I will also automate this. Thanks!

Comment: @User1 The "Here" link is gone ...

Answer (score 2):

While the accepted answer solved this specific problem, the correct way of setting `$ConfirmImpact` preference variable is via session state:

```cs
var sessionState = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault();
sessionState.Variables.Add(new SessionStateVariableEntry("ConfirmPreference", ConfirmImpact.None, ""));

using (PowerShell shell = PowerShell.Create(sessionState))
{
    // execute commands, etc
}
```

(This is for visitors who came here from Google search results)