# Programmatically capturing a confirmation prompt

Tags: c#, powershell

I have made a simple GUI in WPF for running some scripts in powershell.
To run the scripts I use the System.Management.Automation.Powershell class.

My problem is as follows:
In the normal execution of the script, the user is prompted for confirmation
"In order to install this software, some action needs to be performed. would you like to proceed? Y/N?"

How do I programmatically capture this prompt (I have tried to search for an appropriate event in the API and could not find  any event that gets raised when a prompt occurs) to give the control to the user using the gui (or otherwise to the program) in c#?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mean capture an user input from your WPF app or from the powershell interface? The Y/N question, how is this prompted?

Comment: So this is the question asked by PowerShell: " (...) '. You can also install the NuGet provider by running 'Install-PackageProvider -Name NuGet -MinimumVersion 2.8.5.201 -Force'. Do you want PowerShellGet to install and import the NuGet provider now?" and then after the script runs I am able to capture the following:
"A command that prompts the user failed because the host program or the command type does not support the user interaction. The host was attempting to request confirmation with the following message: "..." "

Comment: J, i think you can have a try setting the ExecutionPolicy or ConfirmationPreference before prompting the user, refer to this and see if that can help you on the way: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33366855/how-do-i-set-confirmpreference-none-for-a-powershell-instance

Comment: It sounds like user interaction is not enabled when you run the script this way. So the short answer is that you can't capture the result... Because there won't be anything to capture. The long answer is you can provably enable it by rewriting the script a bit

Comment: You should put the error you mention in your comment into the question. You should be able to suppress the confirmation by running `Install-PackageProvider` with the `-confirm:$false` parameter in your script. You seem to be using some functionality in your script that requires that NuGet is installed so just install it in your script